# "command not found" with custom run script and xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, xcodebuild, run-script

I am running a customized script which includes a command (ios-sim) which should be known to bash (the binary lies in /usr/local/bin, $PATH knows). However, when invoked by xcodebuild the console logs "command not found".

I am able to execute the command manually, but I have no idea why it doesn't work within the run script. I have checked the user but as I expected it is both times the same user...

The line invoking ios-sim:

```
ios-sim launch $(dirname $TEST_HOST) $environment_args --args -SenTest All $test_bundle_path -v
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than relying on `$PATH`, the value of which isn't obvious, use the whole path to `ios-sim`.

Edit your custom script and change:

```
ios-sim launch ...
```

to

```
/usr/local/bin/ios-sim launch ...
```

The reason why using `$PATH` can be dangerous (perhaps too strong a word) is that it's not obvious where it's set.  For example Xcode will use the path that's configured in `/etc/launchd.conf` and `/usr/local/bin` might have been added in `/etc/profile` or `~/.bash_profile`.

- Will `launchd` use the value in `/etc/profile` and thereby pass it to Xcode to use?
- Will scripts started by Xcode use `/etc/profile` or `~/.bash_profile`?

It's complicated and thorough understanding of this environment will doubtless allow you to invoke your command via `$PATH`, however using the fullpath to a command is a simple approach which will always work.